# UIProgressView with bubbles?

Tags: uikit, uipagecontrol, uiprogressview

In the `UINavigationBar`, I want to put a hybrid of `UIProgressView` & `UIPageControl` to show the user what step (page) of the sign up flow they're on and how many steps are left.

It look like the following `UIProgressView` except with bubbles/dots/circles.

[image]

How could I do that? Does UIKit offer such a control? If not, are there any open source versions of that?

Answer (score 0):

There isnt anything like that in UIKit. It should be quite easy to make something custom though.

You could even use a UIProgressView with custom images. see here http://goto11.net/skinning-a-uiprogressview-with-drawrect-and-images/